# Add a class to dynamically created list element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-lists

I have the following code which takes an input from an xml and creates an unordered list.

```
$(function() {
            var map = function() {
                    if ($(this).is("parent")) {
                        var children = $(this).children().map(map).get().join('');
                        $(this).children().remove();
                        var result = "<li class='BGOfDiv'>" + $(this).text();
                        return result + "<ul>" + children + "</ul></li>";
                    }
                    if ($(this).is("Children")) {
                        return "<li class='BGOfDiv'>" + $(this).text() + "</li>";
                    }
                };

                $.get("test.xml", function(data) {
                    var result = $(data).map(map);
                    $("#org").html(result[0]);
                    $("#org").jOrgChart({
                            chartElement : '#chart',
                            dragAndDrop  : false
                        });
                        dragNodes();
                }, "html");

            });
```

Currently,my xml looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Parent>Director
    <Children>Exe Director1</Children>
    <Children>Exe Director2</Children>
    <Parent>Exe Director3
        <Children>Sub Director 1</Children>
        <Children>Sub Director 2</Children>
        <Parent>Sub Director 3
            <Children>Cameraman 1</Children>
            <Children>Cameraman 2</Children>
        </Parent>
    </Parent>    
</Parent>
```

However,the xml will be made to hold the paths of certain images which I need to apply as the background-image for each node.That is my xml will look like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Parent>../images/1.jpg
    <Children>../images/2.jpg</Children>
    <Children>../images/3.jpg</Children>
    <Parent>../images/4.jpg
        <Children>../images/5.jpg</Children>
        <Children>../images/6.jpg</Children>
        <Parent>../images/7.jpg
            <Children>../images/8.jpg</Children>
            <Children>../images/9.jpg</Children>
        </Parent>
    </Parent>    
</Parent>
```

I understand that I will need to use the `.css` property of `jquery` and set the `background-image` when I create the new `<li>` element but I am not able to figure out how that can be done.

Thanks for looking.Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: it's probably not a good idea to name your callback function you pass to `map`, `map`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `$(this).text()` returns the url of the file, you could simply add the style in the `<li>` element

```
"<li class='class' style='background-image: url(" + $(this).text() + ");'>...</li>"
```

Of course you would probably need to setup other CSS like background-position, background-repeat, etc. Or use the short version of the css like

```
"<li class='class' style='background: url(" + $(this).text() + ") no-repeat 0 0;'>...</li>"
```

Comment: yes `$(this).text()` does return the url of the file but the style you mentioned above isn't getting executed in the code.I guess I am giving incorrect urls.Will have a look.Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: Since the background will be set in the HTML page, the image url is relative to the HTML page.

Comment: Did that,but the style doesn't show up when I check the developer tools on chrome.

Comment: Also, you need to make that the li element has enough width and height for the image to show. If you don't set the dimensions (and there's no content, nothing will show up).

Comment: Ultimately,I am doing something stupid here.Thanks,will accept this as the answer.